# Aurelia using featherjs dependency failing to properly import

Tags: aurelia, feathersjs

How do you import featherjs using the style common in Aurelia projects.  This is what I have:

in the build file aurelia.json

```
"dependencies": [
      {
        "name": "socket.io-client",
        "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min"
      },
      {
        "name": "feathers",
        "path": "../node_modules/feathers",
        "main": "client",
        "env": "dev"
      },
      "aurelia-binding",
```

In the app.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from 'feathers';
//import socketio from 'feathers-socketio';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';

    console.log("startup"); 

    const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');

    const app = feathers();
//      .configure(socketio(socket));
  }
}
```

The error looks like this:

```
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildJavaScript'...
Finished 'buildJavaScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
{ uid: 8,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: 
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/steve/project/src/uberproto.js']
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/Users/steve/project/src/uberproto.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'feathers/lib/feathers' ],
     fileName: '/Users/steve/project/node_modules/feathers/lib/feathers.js' },
  duration: [ 0, 161365129 ],
  time: 1484844203606 }
```

Once it gets into processing the dependency it seems to be having path confusion looking for dependencies in featherjs.   I'm pretty new with this stuff, so it is likely something simple, but I haven't figured out the correct way to include this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to install is *feathers-client* not *feathers*.

```
npm i -S feathers-client
```

aurelia.json:

```
{
   "name": "socket.io-client",
   "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min"
},
{
   "name": "feathers-client",
   "path": "../node_modules/feathers-client/dist",
   "main": "feathers"
}
```

app.js:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from 'feathers-client';

export class App {
    constructor() {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
        const app = feathers().configure(feathers.socketio(socket));
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it.  Now I just need to figure out the last dependency, the commented one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765908/aurelia-using-featherjs-dependency-failing-to-properly-import-feathers-socketio

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `main` property. The configuration should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "socket.io-client",
  "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist",
  "main": "socket.io.min"
}
```

Comment: Actually that dependency is working fine, it is the feathersjs dependency that is having an issue.