# Aurelia using featherjs dependency failing to properly import feathers-socketio

Tags: aurelia, feathersjs

How do you import featherjs-socketio using the technique common in Aurelia projects.  A previous question helped me past the second dependency, but the last one seems to have the same fate as the first without a similar workaround. [Aurelia using featherjs depency failing to properly import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747372/aurelia-using-featherjs-depency-failing-to-properly-import)

This is what I have:

in the build file aurelia.json

```
"dependencies": [
          {
            "name": "socket.io-client",
            "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min"
          },
          {
            "name": "feathers-client",
            "path": "../node_modules/feathers-client/dist",
            "main": "feathers"
          },
          {
            "name": "feathers-socketio",
            "path": "../node_modules/feathers-socketio",
            "main": "client"
          },
          "aurelia-binding",
```

In the app.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from 'feathers';
import socketio from 'feathers-socketio';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';

    console.log("startup"); 

    const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');

    const app = feathers()
      .configure(socketio(socket));
  }
}
```

The error looks like this:

```
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildJavaScript'...
Finished 'buildJavaScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
{ uid: 8,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: 
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/steve/project/src/feathers-socket-commons/client.js']
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/Users/steve/project/src/feathers-socket-commons/client.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'feathers-socketio/lib/client' ],
     fileName: '/Users/steve/project/node_modules/feathers-socketio/lib/client.js' },
  duration: [ 0, 281071327 ],
  time: 1484922063672 }
```

Once it gets into processing the dependency it seems to be having path confusion looking for dependencies in featherjs-socketio.   I asked a previous question about the feathers dependency which is resolved, but not sure what to do with this one.

feathers-socket-commons is listed in the node modules, but it seems to be looking in my project folder so that is why I'm assuming it is confused on path, or simply not a client library?  Strange because the examples show using this node module, but examples also show using 'feathers' instead of 'feathers-client'.  This is the client example given in feathers-socketio:

Client use

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from 'feathers/client';
import socketio from 'feathers-socketio/client';

const socket = io('http://path/to/api');
const app = feathers()
  .configure(socketio(socket));
```

**SOLUTION** Thanks to the marked answer below.

aurelia.json changes to:

```
"dependencies": [
          {
            "name": "socket.io-client",
            "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min"
          },
          {
            "name": "feathers-client",
            "path": "../node_modules/feathers-client/dist",
            "main": "feathers"
          },
          "aurelia-binding",
```

app.js becomes:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from 'feathers-client';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';

    console.log("startup");

    const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');

    const app = feathers().configure(feathers.socketio(socket));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to install *feathers-socketio* it is included in *feathers-client* among other plugins.

```
configure(socketio(socket))
```

becomes:

```
configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
```

according to the [feathers-socketio](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-client)

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  So for the newby like myself, remove the feathers-socketio dependency in aurelia.json (otherwise it will still fail) and change last line of app.js to: const app = feathers().configure(feathers.socketio(socket));

Comment: When you say according to 'feathers-socketio'.  The readme shows the use of the import of feathers-socketio.  strange.  I quoted the example in the original question from the readme. Guess it hasn't been changed?  Seems like there are a million ways to do everything in js. :) Either way lots of thanks for getting me over the hurdle.

Comment: The Readme at https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-client (which is what you were importing) and the docs at https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/feathers.html#feathers-client should show hot to set up the browser build.

Comment: How do I import a plugin not included in the client dist such as feathers-offline-snapshot

Comment: I meant to say feathers-offline-realtime the snapshot seems to work fine but something is wrong when you add realtime to the aurelia.json